# find out which column matches in pg sequelize conditional query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have four columns in a `movie` table and three of these columns should be unique `title`, `description`, `year`.

When I insert a row into this table e.g.

```
   { 
        title: 'Long Walk',
        description: 'Walk to the moon and beyond'
        year: 1890
    }
```

I check if any of the three already exists in the table throw error.
For that I'm using sequelize OR condition on all three columns

```
   const movie = await this.model.findOne({
      where: {
        [Op.or]: [
          { title: { [Op.iLike]: title} },
          { description: { [Op.iLike]: description} },
          { year: { [Op.iLike]: year} },
        ],
      },
    });
```

This query tells me if a record already exists if any of the three column matches. Is there a way to know which column matched? I want to know names of the columns that matched.

E.g if after the input given above was inserted into the table, if I give another input

```
{ 
        title: 'Blue Beach',
        description: 'Its a movie about a beach.'
        year: 1890
    }
```

This should throw an error as the year `1890` already exists in the table and output me something like 'year column duplicate'.

Comment: I do not think the `findOne` will find all records that you need to, or want to check. see: https://dbfiddle.uk/hiTjurds

Comment: Its ok even if one duplicate is found. 
Also, I don't get the output there. I mean there are  no unique constraints on the columns and I don't understand what exactly are you trying to show :)

Comment: You should look at the output, to know which column has an already existing record, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/MKYRp6ic

Comment: How do I write it in sequelize? The column names that have duplicate records

Comment: If you need that ALL three column values should be unique you need to use `Op.and` instead of `Op.or`. Also you should use `Op.eq` instead of `Op.like` if you don't use any wildcards in searching values.

Comment: @Anatoly This is a 'find' query. I wanna check if any (`or`) of the three fields already exist in db - throw error with the matched column names.
Also, I'm using Op.iLike now for case-insensitive query check.

Comment: `three of these columns should be unique title, description, year` means that a combination of a certain three values should be unique, right?

Comment: No. The column itself should be unique